# Searching in Laravel relationship for second table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two table having polymorphic relationships.

Table1 is history

```
id|amount|type|created_at|updated_at
```

Table2 is accounts

```
id|amount|name|account_number|accountable_id|accountable_type|created_at|updated_at
```

history have the summary of accounts table.
accounts table is having polymorphic fields (accountable)

Now I am executing a query in history table results includes the accounts table also.

The question is I want to search some data in accounts table too say payer name is in account table. So when I hit query on history table I will pass payer name with that so it can fetch only that accounts having the specific payer name.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set up a relationship between history and accounts so you can query along the lines of:

```
$histories = Histories::whereHas(
        'accounts'
        function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->where('name', $name);
        }
    )->get();
```

But your question is not really clear, and you don't have a names field in accounts in the limited schema you provided, so I can't give a better answer.

Read more here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships